# Can be possible install Victor mono font un a WSL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, wsl-2

Im new in this and i hope anyone can help me

I tried to install the font from the caché in the terminal in wsl in Windows. I have installed the font in Windows but wsl not .

I tried with
Apt-caché search Victor Mono

But it doesn’t works and with roboto it does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Installing a Font in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

To install a font in WSL, follow these steps:

1. **Check Font Location**: Confirm that the font file (e.g., VictorMono.ttf) is located in a directory accessible from your WSL instance. You can copy the font file to your WSL home directory for simplicity.
2. **Install Font**: You can use the `fc-cache` command to update the font cache in WSL and make the font available. Open a terminal in your WSL instance and run the following commands:

   ```bash
   sudo cp /mnt/c/path/to/VictorMono.ttf /usr/local/share/fonts/
   sudo fc-cache -fv
   ```

   **Note that** `/mnt/c` is the path to the C: drive in Windows when you're working within WSL.
3. Verify Installation: You can verify that the font is installed by running the following command in your WSL terminal:

   ```bash
   fc-list | grep "Victor Mono"
   ```

Hope this help !!